# how to implement 2 different ads to appear to the bottom

Tags: android, layout, ads

I use millennial media and admob ads. I have problem in how to implement both of them.
I want the ads to be show at the bottom of the application.

I use  sth like that for relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
<com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
      android:id="@+id/mmadview1" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ... 
      app:adType="MMBannerAdBottom"
      app:height="60"
      app:width="480" />

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView1"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"  
                         ...
                         ...
                          ..
                          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"     />

  <TextView..../>

  <Button.../>
```

Also, i have some xmls with linear layout:

```
 <LinearLayout ...
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  
 >
<com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
  android:id="@+id/mmadview5" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ... 
 ...
   app:adType="MMBannerAdBottom"
   app:height="60"
   app:width="480" />

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView5"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER" />

 <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


  <TextView  android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="180dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/num_cores"
android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    />

   <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip" /> 

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/core_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/num_cores"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
   />

 </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/halftimecores"

    />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/timecores"
    />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/core_calcs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

  </LinearLayout>
```

I just want the ads to be show at the bottom.How can i do that?
(Right now , either they appear at top or they don't appear)

Answer (score 0):

If you use LinearLayout put them after Button (@+id/core_calcs) if you use RelativeLayout
use android:layout_below="@+id/core_calcs" for first add and android:layout_below="@+id/firstAdd_ID"  for second add

Comment: :hello,it crashes giving "exception caused by :android.widget.button".

Comment: Did you put ads after Button block in LinearLayout?